# How and where JDBC connection(s) are created in Spark Structured Streaming job's forEachBatch loop?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark structured streaming job which reads from Kafka and writes the dataframe to Oracle inside foreachBatch loop. My code is as below. I understand that number of parallel connections will depend on ***numPartitions*** configuration but confused on how the connection is reused across executor, tasks and micro batches.

1. If a connection is made once at all executors then will it
   remain open for future micro-batches as well or a new connection
   will be established for each iteration.
2. If a connection is made for each task inside executor (eg- 10 tasks, then 10 connections) then does it mean that every time new connections will be established for each loop iteration and its task

   ```
   StreamingDF.writeStream
   .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("30 seconds"))
   .foreachBatch{
      (microBatchDF: DataFrame, batchID) =>
    {
   microBatchDF.write
     .format("jdbc")
     .option("url", jdbcUrl)
     .option("dbtable", "my_schema.my_table")
     .option("user", username)
     .option("password", password)
     .option("batchsize", 10000)
     .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
     .save(
   }
   ```

What is the best way to reuse the same connections to minimise batch execution time?

Comment: I think connection is at task level.

Comment: Even I think so, I am running this in my local where executor is same as driver. But the number of parallel connections that I see on my oracle database are same as number of cores that I define while creating spark context. (Provided the number of numPartitions > number of cores)

Also, from oracle connection logs, I can see a new connection is created for every task which means that same connection is not reused for another task. But I am not sure what is the best practice to handle this scenario of writing to database inside foreachBatch loop

Comment: Maybe try using a connection pool? The way you're doing it now, the connection is created and dropped every batch...

Comment: @LuckyGuess How do I do that? I am pretty new to spark/scala so any reference link will be helpful